# Copy selected data from one workbook to another

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a bit new here & also new with VB. I have 2 workbooks. In WB 1 some data are there. Now I need to copy those data to WB 2. But not all of them. In srcsht there are 9 columns. In destsht there are only 5. Plus based on column 4 in srcsht i.e. Region, i need to copy the data for only East & not the rest, which is there at destsht in column 2.
Another thing is as i enter more rows in srcsht, the same should be increased in destsht too.

Comment: Could you post the code to which you are referring?

Answer (score 0):

Here an example

```
Workbook("WB 1").Worksheets("worksheet1").Range("A2:B14").Copy _
Destination:=Workbooks("WB 2").Worksheets("worksheet1").Range("A1")
```

It selects the datas from the workbook named `WB 1` which are in the `worksheet1`. You put the range you want. You `.copy` the datas selected and you do the same with the destination (where you want to past the datas copied)

Just chose the datas you want to copy and the destination